# 2 external monitors (DP+VGA) 8570p / Intel HD4000 / QM77Chipset

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, vga

I've read QM77 chipset supports only up to 2 displays. I would connect two external monitors, so I'd have 3 displays (at this moment I have laptop screen, one external monitor over displayport (Dell U2412M) and I would connect one old Sasmsung monitor via VGA). Is the only option to buy USB3.0->VGA adapter? I read that the USB-VGA adapters (mainly based on fresco FL2000) cause a lot of problems with flickering screen. So maybe there is another RELIABLE solution with my old elitebook laptop. Maybe use express slot for graphic card will be better? Thanks!

Windows 7
8GB RAM
(I also use port replicator if it matters - the small one version HSTNN-I11X )

**UPDATE:**

I've just read about "daisy chain" display port standard (e.g. Dell U2515h supports it). Can "daisy chain" overcome chipset support display number limit?

Comment: I count 3 video outputs on the port replicator (albeit of 3 different types). Have you tried using any combination of 2 of these. I used to have a similar docking/replicator for a laptop and had two monitor connected to it, and my laptop open at the same time for 3 displays

Comment: When I plug second external monitor I see in windows "display and resolution" window all three displays including laptop screen. But one of external monitor is black. When I right-click to activate it, it runs but the previous external monitor automaticlly turns off. I've tried different configurations using windows settings and Intel graphics panel and result is the same: at one time I can expand(or replicate) laptop screen using only one of the external monitors. Both are working but not at the same time. I've tried to connect to port replicator and directly to laptop,  no difference :(

Comment: I've bought adapter with DisplayLink chip (about 35 USD) and it's working without problem for me. There is only small lag when I lunch video on that external screen, but for reading it's perfect.